# Store values in an array and pass it in url

Tags: php, arrays

```
$deposit=$_POST['amountdeposit'];
$arr= array();
for($i=0;$i<10;$i++)
{
    if($arr[$i]=='\0')
  { $arr[$i]= array("$deposit");
     }
     break;  
}
$page= "step2.php?arr=$arr";

    header("Location:$page");

?>
```

what i want to do is each time there's a change in `$deposit` , this value is stored in `$arr[$i]` and then it is passed in a url so that i could use GET on that `step2.php` page.
What I see is just `arr=array` instead of values `:/` please help me.

Comment: See [`http_build_query`](http://php.net/http_build_query).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want [http_query_string](http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php). It will do exactly what you want.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of other comments have recommended [http_query_string](http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php), however I would use [serialize](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php) along with [urlencode](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php).

Replace:

```
$page= "step2.php?arr=$arr";
```

with:

```
$page= "step2.php?arr=" . urlencode(serialize($arr));
```

Then when you get to step2.php, `unserialize(urldecode($_GET['arr']))` will contain your array as you originally built it.